# Decoding DataMatrix containing GS1 seperator with Python

Tags: python, datamatrix

So I am trying to decode a data matrix that contains data that is in ISO/IEC 15434 syntax for high-capacity ADC media using Python.

I am using this code:

```
     def extract_dataMatrix(self):
        dm_read = DataMatrix()
        #return (dm_read.decode(self.content.size[0],self.content.size[1], buffer(self.content.tobytes())))
        self.informations.append(Datamatrix(dm_read.decode(self.content.size[0],self.content.size[1], buffer(self.content.tobytes()))))
```

The output is:
[image: Scanned barcode message]

I need to find the [RS] and [GS] separators to be able to split the output into multiple components.

If anyone know another library faster than pydmtx is will be good too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The character showing as a box containing 001E is RS, and 001D is GS. (These are standard control codes in ASCII.)